# Can I use a wildcard like https://sub-*.domain.com in my CSP?

Tags: content-security-policy, wildcard-subdomain

I have a domain that has three different subdomains (the naming convention is `sub-environment.domain.com`). I want to add them to the Content Security Policy, but was wondering if I can use a wildcard like this:

```
sub-prod.domain.com
sub-stage.domain.com
sub-demo.domain.com
```

Would it be possible to specify `sub-*.domain.com` in my CSP to cover all three subdomains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the latest [Content Security Policy Level 3 W3C Working Draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#framework-directive-source-list); a wildcard in a *host source* can only appear at the beginning of the host part:

> ```
> host-source = [ scheme-part "://" ] host-part [ ":" port-part ] [ path-part ]
> host-part   = "*" / [ "*." ] 1*host-char *( "." 1*host-char )
> ```

Therefore, you cannot use `https://sub-*.domain.com` as a host source. Instead, you'll have to specify all three of your subdomains in your CSP.